# Mathematical relationship between Area under ROC curve and accuracy

Tags: probability, accuracy, auc, calibration

Area under receiver operating characteristic curve (AUROC) is a threshold-independent metric for “discrimination”. It tells you about the model's ability to discriminate between cases (positive examples) and non-cases (negative examples).
Is there a mathematical relationship between area under receiver operating characteristic curve and accuracy?

The best I could found was AAAI2021 [paper](https://taih20.github.io/papers/6/CameraReady/calib_ref.pdf):

$$E[A] = \pi(1-\pi)(2r-1)+1/2-C $$
Where A: accuracy, pi: ratio of positive examples, C: constant, r: AUROC, which is calculated from expression for Expected calibration error:
$$ECE=\sum |B_m||E[A]_m -C_m]/n $$
under the assumptions of binary classification (n=2), Number of bins for calibration m = 1 and $$E[A]<C$$